# Full text search with different types besides String in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to use full text search in MongoDB, and I know the solution of using text indexes (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/). But, this solution is meant for searching on String type fields only.

How can I perform full text search on other types as well? Suppose I have a collection with documents in which I have fields from a variety of types like String, Number etc.

What can I do?

P.S: I use MongoDB native driver for Nodejs.

Comment: Consider MongoDB Atlas Search which supports multiple datatypes https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search

Answer (score 0):

**Wildcard Indexing**
there can be scenarios where you want any text content in your documents to be searchable. Maybe this will help you.

```
db.collection.createIndex({"$**":"text"})
```

Comment: But if I have a field whose type is Number? This search will not be performed on this field.
Somehow I need to convert all the fields to String and then perform a search.